# Docker COPY fails with no such file or directory, but i am root and can access the file

Tags: linux, docker

Simple dockerfile like this:

```
FROM tomcat:latest
RUN cp -R /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
COPY /home/dockeradmin/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Third statement fails saying no such file or directory.
I am running this as root, inside /root.
/home/dockeradmin and *.war file is owned by dockeradmin user, but as root i have access to it.

I can run `ls /home/dockeradmin/*.war` without any issue.

`RUN cp /home/dockeradmin/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps`

also fails with
cp: cannot stat '/home/dockeradmin/*.war': No such file or directory
I can also run `stat /home/dockeradmin/*.war` without any issue.
It has 664 permission, changed to 777, no go still.

If i copy the Dockerfile to the /home/dockeradmin and change the instruction:

```
COPY ./*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

It works fine.

Not sure why the first option has an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Docker `COPY` `<src>` is interpreted as relative path to the docker build context. See [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

Comment: Yes. this was the issue. All paths in COPY are resolved as relative to where you are running docker build from . So /home/dockeradmin/*.war actually became /root/home/dockeradmin/*.war when running it from root folder. And that path did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

the destination must ends with `/`

ie: `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` is correct, not `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps`